# How do I enable drag drop of a file onto a NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I enable drag drop of a file onto a NSTextField ?

I thought when I drop a file from filesystem to a NSTextField in my app, the path to the file is automatically written in the field.

Instead I can't drop it, and the field remains empty.

I've added this line:

```
[myTextField registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
```

but it doesn't work.

I couldn't find any drag&drop related method in the delegates: `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` or  `NSTextFieldDelegate`.

Thanks

Comment: check [this tutorial](http://www.stone.com/The_Cocoa_Files/Ins_and_Outs_of_Drag_and_D.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to [subclass the `NSTextField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/HandlingDrops.html) and override the `-performDragOperation:` method. Apple has several examples of how to handle dropped files in their [Drag and Drop Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html).

Answer (score 1):

In case you set the NSTextFields behavior to editable you can drop a file right away without a line of code. Xcode 11, but also worked i earlier versions.

[image]